# Python 3.6, web crawler using Selenium, cannot grab the dates and ratings of user reviews from Google Play Store

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am working on a project of web crawler using `Selenium` with `Python 3.6` in a `Jupyter Notebook`.

The goal is to grab the reviews and their corresponding dates and ratings of an APP.

The target webpage is

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.silvrr.installment&hl=en_US&gl=US&showAllReviews=true.

[image]

I can get the reviews but I failed to grab their dates and ratings.

The code I used to grab the reviews is shown below：

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.silvrr.installment&hl=en_US&gl=US&showAllReviews=true' 
path = r"D:\Term 1\Cloud Computing\Session 4-5\CC_ETL\chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path) #Obrir un navegador Chrome
browser.get(url)

content = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('UD7Dzf')
User_Review = []  #Create an empty list to store the user reviews

for i in (range(0,40)):  
    first = {'Review -{}'.format(i+1):content[i].text}
    User_Review.append(first)
User_Review
```

I then tried to grab the date with the class name `"p2TkOb"`:

```
date = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('p2TkOb')
```

but it failed to return the specific dates. Instead, it returned some web elements shown below:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b0e4c4f85a982c03a64302931a3474d1", element="dd95dfb2-c8da-47fc-8d5e-16a0ce010db7")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b0e4c4f85a982c03a64302931a3474d1", element="7fd1ab9a-b654-4ec0-b6c7-e8bd5260d0db")>,
```

Also, there two kinds of dates, one of the users and another for the developer, whose class names are the same. **However, I only aim to grab the dates of user reviews.**

[image]

I also got troubled in locating the element of ratings, for example, `div aria-label="Rated 1 stars out of five stars"`.

Can anybody please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That class works fine

Comment: you have to use `.text` on `web element` to get text. And when you have list then you have to use `for`-loop for this - ie. `date_txt = [x.text for x in date]`

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Rated 1 stars out of five stars"]')` ?

Comment: I wouldn't create keys `Review-1`, `Review-2`, etc because later it makes only problems - to get element you have to know number and generate key `Review-{}`. It could be simpler to keep it as list or as dictionaries with the same key `Review` without number.

Comment: instead of getting `content` with class `UD7Dzf` you should get external `div` which keeps `content`, `user name` and `date` (ie. `d15Mdf bAhLNe`) and later use relative xpath to get first date`p2TkOb` inside this `div`, and relative xpath to get `content` in this `div` - and this way you always get only user's date for this `content`. Simply: it is wrong idea to search separatelly `content` and separatelly `date`. If some `content` or `date` will be empty then it may skip it and later you get `content` with `date` for next `content` - and you can't control it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea to search separatelly `content` and separatelly `date`.

You should get `div` which keeps both `content` and `date` and later use relative `find_element_by_...` to get `content` and `date` in this `div`. This way you get `date` for this `content` and you can control it.

I use `'d15Mdf bAhLNe'` to get divs which keep both `content` and `date` (every `div` groups all in one review). And later I search `content` and `date` inside every `div` separatelly - using `item.find...` instead of `browser.find...` - and I get single `content` and singel `date` and I'm sure that this `date` is for this `content`.

---

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.silvrr.installment&hl=en_US&gl=US&showAllReviews=true' 

path = r"D:\Term 1\Cloud Computing\Session 4-5\CC_ETL\chromedriver"
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(path) #Obrir un navegador Chrome
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(url)

cards = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('d15Mdf.bAhLNe')  # it has to be `dot` in place of `space`

user_reviews = []  # Create an empty list to store the user reviews

for number, item in enumerate(cards, 1):  
    review = item.find_element_by_class_name('UD7Dzf').text
    date = item.find_element_by_class_name('p2TkOb').text
    user = item.find_element_by_class_name('X43Kjb').text
    rated = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="pf5lIe"]/div').get_attribute('aria-label').split(' ')[1]

    user_reviews.append({
               'number': number, 
               'review': review, 
               'date': date, 
               'user': user,
               'rated': rated,
    })

for item in user_reviews:  
    print('---', item['number'], '---')
    print('date:', item['date'])
    print('user:', item['user'])
    print('rated:', item['rated'])
    print('review:', item['review'][:50], '...')
```

Result:

```
--- 1 ---
date: January 9, 2021
user: NICASIO NICOSIA
rated: 1
review: I used to love this app because of the payment ter ...
--- 2 ---
date: February 3, 2021
user: Shitta Soewarno
rated: 1
review: After I updated the application I could no longer  ...
--- 3 ---
date: January 25, 2021
user: Jennifer Jones
rated: 2
review: Used to love this alot and i always pay back on ti ...
--- 4 ---
date: February 5, 2021
user: Noy D Junior
rated: 3
review: Applications that helped out so much. But now I'm  ...
--- 5 ---
date: January 31, 2021
user: Syuhada Husni
rated: 1
review: it suddenly logged me out and now i cannot log in  ...
```

---

**BTW:** Selenium converts `find_element_by_class_name('name')` to `css selector` with `dot` at the beginning - `.name` - but it has problem with mulit names `find_element_by_class_name('name1 name2')`. It should put `dot` before every name and create `.name1.name2` but it adds `dot` only at the beginnig `.name1 name2` so I add manually `dot` between names in

```
find_elements_by_class_name('d15Mdf.bAhLNe')
```

---

**BTW:** It is not good idea to create unique keys `Review-1`, `Review-2` because later it is problem to get `review` - you have to know what number to use in `Review-{}`. It is better to use the same key `review` in all items.

---

**BTW:** `xpath` starts with `dot` (`.//div`) to create relative xpath which searchs only inside `item`.

---

I put it on GitHub [furas/python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__/play.google.com%20-%20selenium)